# How to add a stop condition to ngFor cycle

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

Im building this web app where the goal is to create ion-components from objects.

Im facing this issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtBgm.jpg

I've already tried using ngIf but I think the problem is in the fact that im creating the objects inside the array.

Here goes some crucial code:

**--Inside the template --**

```
 <ion-item
*ngFor="let comp of composals; let i = index;"
>
<ion-label>{{ composal.content[i] }}</ion-label>
  <ion-radio
    slot="start"
    name="asda"
    value="{{ comp.value }}"
    color="{{ comp.color }}"
  ></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent {

title = 'Formulário';
mySplits: any;
public answersLength: number;

composals = [
  new Composal('#0000FF', 'checkbox', 'radio_1', 'Já realizou algum tratamento de Ortodentia anteriormente?', 'Conteudo1,Conteudo2,Conteudo3,Conteudo4,Conteudo5'),
  new Composal('#0000FF', 'checkbox', 'radio_2', 'Como sentiu as boas vindas do gabinete?', 'Conteudo2, Conteudo3'),
  new Composal('#0000FF', 'checkbox', 'radio_3', 'E a primeira conversa com o médico?', 'Conteudo3,Conteudo1'),
//    new Composal('primary', 'textbox', '', 'Insira o texto', ''),
];
```

The goal is that the output be like:

Já realizou algum tratamento de Ortodentia anteriormente?
Conteudo1
Conteudo2
Conteudo3
Conteudo4
Conteudo5

Como sentiu as boas vindas do gabinete?
Conteudo2
Conteudo3

E a primeira conversa com o médico?
Conteudo3
Conteudo1

Comment: Can you add your `Composal` class?

Comment: It is not very clear what your are trying to achieve, kindly clear mention your goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that for each composal you have an ion-item and depending for the content you have a ion-radio-button you should use two *ngFor, one for the composal and other for each content

html:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let comp of composals">
    <ion-label>{{ comp.label }}</ion-label>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let content of comp.content">
        <ion-label>{{content}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" value="biff" checked></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

interface Composal {
  color: string;
  label: string;
  content: string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  title = 'Formulário';
  mySplits: any;
  public answersLength: number;
  composals: Composal[] = [
    { color: '#0000FF', label: 'Já realizou algum tratamento de Ortodentia anteriormente?', content: ['Conteudo1', 'Conteudo2', 'Conteudo3', 'Conteudo4', 'Conteudo5'] },
    { color: '#0000FF', label: 'Como sentiu as boas vindas do gabinete?', content: ['Conteudo2', 'Conteudo3'] },
    { color: '#0000FF', label: 'E a primeira conversa com o médico?', content: ['Conteudo3', 'Conteudo1'] },
  ];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Now I'm just guessing how your class look like, But this is quite the idea. Also you need to group the radio-buttons in a radio-group if you want so.

Here is the stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-g5ecg4

Comment: Works just fine! Thank you :)